# Select an element's contents without certain descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the parent element `.search-result-item` and skip the h3 tag in it and btn-grey class from selection. my code is here

```
$('div.search-result-item:not(h3 .btn-grey)').click(function(e){
    console.log('1');
});
```

but it selects h3 and btn-grey also what i  doing wrong?

my HTML is here

```
<div data-id="52c53ccfaea0837f318b470c" class="search-result-item ">
        <div>
                <div class="search_result">
                        <div class="picture"><img width="195" height="130" src="/images/not_available.png" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="info">
                                <h3>
                                        <a href="/course-detail/masters/management-with-human-resource-management/full-time/university-of-chester-faculty-of-business-enterprise-and-lifelong-learning/uk/52c53ccfaea0837f318b470c" title="Management with Human Resource Management">
                                        Management with Human Resource Management                                                                       </a>
                                </h3>
                                <p>
                                        <strong>Entry Requirements: </strong>IELTS : 6.5
                                </p>
                                <a data-id="52c53ccfaea0837f318b470c" class="request-info" title="Request Info">
                                        <button class="btn btn-yellow">Request Info</button>
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn btn-grey" href="/course-detail/masters/management-with-human-resource-management/full-time/university-of-chester-faculty-of-business-enterprise-and-lifelong-learning/uk/52c53ccfaea0837f318b470c" title="Course Details">
                                        Course Details
                                </a>
                        </div> 
                </div><!-- .search_result -->    
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you don't want to fire that click event on clicking `h3` and `.btn-grey`?

Comment: yes i don't want to fire on clicking h3 and .btn-grey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead. Do the filtering after the event has fired by checking what element fired the event:

```
$('div.search-result-item').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is('h3,.btn-grey')) {
        console.log('1');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting what is going on. When you bind an even to a parent element, all events that happen on child elements will bubble to the parent and trigger the event on the parent. Using `:not()` will not change that fact. You instead need to test the `event.target` inside the event handler to ensure that the target element was *not* one of the elements that you didn't want to trigger the event.

```
$('div.search-result-item').click(function(e){
    if ( !$(e.target).is("h3,.btn-grey") ) {
        console.log('1');
    }    
});
```

Comment: `.btn-grey` is not a descendant of `h3`.

Comment: i fixed that issue about 8 and a half min ago